# Given a dataframe, how do I bucket columns according to their names and merge columns in the same bucket into one?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe with (for example) 10 columns: `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j`

I want to bucket these columns as follows: `a,b,c` into `x`, `d,f,g` into `y`, `e,h,i` into `z` and `j` into `j`.

Each row of the output will have the `x` column value equal to the non-NaN `a` or `b` or `c` value of the original df. In case of multiple non-NaN values for `a,b,c` columns for a particular row in the original df, the output df will just contain a list of those non-NaN values.

To give an example, if the original df is (`-` just means `NaN` to save typing effort):

```
   a b c d e f g h i j
0  1 - - - 2 - 4 3 - -
1  - 6 - 0 4 - - - - 2
2  - 3 2 - - - - 1 - 9
```

The output will be:

```
   x    y    z    j
0  1    4  [2,3]  -
1  6    0    4    2
2 [3,2] -    1    9
```

Is there an efficient way of doing this? I'm not even able to get started using conventional methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way is to create a dictionary with your mappings, apply your column names, stack and to apply your groupby operation and unstack to your original shape.

I couldn't see any logic in your mappings so it will have to be a manual operation I'm afraid.

```
buckets = {'x': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'y': ['d', 'f', 'g'], 'z': ['e', 'h', 'i'], 'j': 'j'}

df.columns = df.columns.map( {i : x for x,y in buckets.items() for i in y})
```

---

```
out = df.stack().groupby(level=[0,1]).agg(list).unstack(1)[buckets.keys()]

print(out)

        x    y       z    j
0     [1]  [4]  [2, 3]  NaN
1     [6]  [0]     [4]  [2]
2  [3, 2]  NaN     [1]  [9]
```

Comment: You could also use `fillna` after map to fill in values if there are many columns which are not going to be bucketed. Something like `cols = pd.Series(df.columns)` then `df.columns = cols.map({i: x for x, y in buckets.items() for i in y}).fillna(cols)`.

Comment: Thanks! When I'm doing the `agg(list)` step, it's giving an error saying `'type' object is not iterable`. Something's going wrong at that step

Comment: @HenryEcker ah nice, that solves the problem of having `j` in the dictionary which felt redundant

Comment: @user9343456 what is the output `d` here ?  `d = df.stack().groupby(level=[0,1])` please `print(d.head.to_dict())` if the data is not sensitive and add it to your question.

Comment: @Umar.H: What you mentioned in the previous comment is not giving an error: the output is like `{(0, 'val1'): 'col1', (0, 'val2'): 'col2', (1, 'val1'): 'col1', (1, 'val3'): 'col3', (1, 'val4'): 'col4', (2, 'val2'): 'col2', (2, 'val5'): 'col5'}`. So tuples as keys.

Answer (score 1):

First create the `dict` for mapping , the `groupby`

```
d = {'a':'x','b':'x','c':'x','d':'y','f':'y','g':'y','e':'z','h':'z','i':'z','j':'j'}
out = df.groupby(d,axis=1).agg(lambda x : [y[y!='-']for y in x.values])
Out[138]: 
     j       x    y       z
0   []     [1]  [4]  [2, 3]
1  [2]     [6]  [0]     [4]
2  [9]  [3, 2]   []     [1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with a very basic approach, let's define our buckets and simply iterate, then clean up:

```py
buckets = {
    'x': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'y': ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    'z': ['g', 'h', 'i'],
    'j': ['j']
}

def clean(val):
    val = [x for x in val if not np.isnan(val)]
    if len(val) == 0:
        return np.nan
    elif len(val) == 1:
        return val[0]
    else:
        return val

new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for new_col, old_cols in buckets.items():
    new_df[key] = df[old_cols].values.tolist().apply(clean)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it.

First, we define a method to perform the row-wise bucketing operation.

```py
def bucket_rows(row):
    row = row.dropna().to_list()  
    if len(row) == 0:
        row = [np.nan]
    return row
```

Then, we can use the `pandas.DataFrame.apply` method to map this function onto each row on a dataframe (here, a sub-dataframe, if you will, since we'll get the sub-df using the column names).

I have implemented everything in the following code snippet.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

bucket_cols=[["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "f", "g"], ["e", "h","i"], ["j"]]
bucket_names=["x", "y", "z", "j"]

buckets = {}

def bucket_rows(row):
    row = row.dropna().to_list()  # applying pd.Series.dropna method to remove NaN values
    # if the list is empty, populate it with NaN
    if len(row) == 0:
        row = [np.nan]
    # returns bucketed row
    return row

# looping through buckets and perforing bucketing operation
for idx, cols in enumerate(bucket_cols):
    bucket = df[cols].apply(bucket_rows, axis=1).to_list()
    buckets[idx] = bucket

# creating bucketted df from buckets dict
df_bucketted = pd.DataFrame(buckets)
```